# get a list/array of the names of the the properties of a java bean in the order they appear in the source file

Tags: java, reflection, javabeans

I have a class like

```
class A {

    private String property1;

    private String property2;

    private String property3;

    // constructor , getters , setters 

}
```

it is possible to get a list/array of the names of properties of this class in the order they appear in the source file ?  like `["property1", "property2", "property3"]`

Comment: May I ask why? This sounds like a *very* bad idea.

Comment: In some other parts of my code i need to "print" the data of this class in certain order. This class in the real case has a lot of properties and can change (as the order) so, i can write this array/list by myself to get the order i need but if it is possible to get it from the class it would be better for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that you can't.  The information you require is not available at runtime from the .class files.

> In some other parts of my code i need to "print" the data of this class in certain order. This class in the real case has a lot of properties and can change (as the order) so, i can write this array/list by myself to get the order i need but if it is possible to get it from the class it would be better for me.

Here are some better ways to solve this problem:

- Sort the properties before printing, by name or by type name, or something that makes sense.
- Embed an array in the bean class (or another class) that defines the bean property order.
- Create a separate metadata file that specifies the bean property order.

You could do some build time pre-processing of your source code to extract the order of the properties and (say) write them to a file.  But frankly, I think it is better to detach these aspects; e.g. so that your system integrators / end-users could tweak the property order without changing the source code.

Answer (score 1):

> it is possible to get a list/array of the names of properties of this class

Yes, using [`Class.getDeclaredFields()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields%28%29)

> in the order they appear in the source file

No, not with any kind of guarantee unless you parse the source file.

Comment: What about using debug info to sort according to line numbers?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - that could only work for properties with initializers.  The line number debug info maps from (bytecode) PC numbers to line numbers.

Answer (score 1):

This is not precisely possible. [`Class#getDeclaredFields`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields%28%29) makes no guarantee about the ordering of the fields returned. However, in the test I just conducted, the fields were indeed returned in their declaration order.